# Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 2404:6800:4005:807::200e:80

Tags: linux, debian

Im trying to setup a dante socks5 in my ubuntu 20.04 and dante sockets seems cant connect, I am following this tutorial

https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-danted-proxy-socks5/#step-22---dante-configuration

Please see below details, hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

==============================================================

Here is the command for me to test

curl -x socks5://192.168.1.8:1080 google.com

And here is the response

Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 2404:6800:4005:807::200e:80

==============================================================

ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:2b:4a:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
valid_lft 80154sec preferred_lft 80154sec
inet6 2001:4450:8152:5b00:11de:c2ee:2172:d495/64 scope global temporary dynamic
valid_lft 259195sec preferred_lft 79752sec
inet6 2001:4450:8152:5b00:e87f:844c:c41:140b/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
valid_lft 259195sec preferred_lft 172795sec
inet6 fe80::aaeb:4af7:f61f:fac9/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

==============================================================

nano /etc/danted.conf

logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: enp0s3 port = 1080
external: enp0s3
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error connect disconnect
}
client block {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: connect error
}
socks pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error connect disconnect
}
socks block {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: connect error
}

==============================================================

netstat -nlpt | grep dant

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.8:1080        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7875/danted
tcp6       0      0 fe80::aaeb:4af7:f6:1080 :::*                    LISTEN      7875/danted
tcp6       0      0 2001:4450:8152:5b0:1080 :::*                    LISTEN      7875/danted
tcp6       0      0 2001:4450:8152:5b0:1080 :::*                    LISTEN      7875/danted

==============================================================

ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From

---

1323                       ALLOW       Anywhere
1080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
1323 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

==============================================================

systemctl status danted

danted.service - SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/danted.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-01 10:58:14 PST; 1h 8min ago
Docs: man:danted(8)
man:danted.conf(5)
Process: 7859 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c       uid=`sed -n -e "s/[[:space:]]//g" -e "s/#.*//" -e "/^user\.privileged/{s/[^:]*://p;q;}" /etc/danted.conf`;      if [ -n "$uid" ]; then                  touch /var/run/dante>
Main PID: 7875 (danted)
Tasks: 20 (limit: 3525)
Memory: 10.4M
CGroup: /system.slice/danted.service
├─7875 /usr/sbin/danted
├─7883 danted: monitor
├─7897 danted: request
├─7898 danted: request
├─7899 danted: request
├─7900 danted: request
├─7907 danted: request
├─7925 danted: request
├─8367 danted: request
├─8374 danted: request
├─8378 danted: request
├─8382 danted: request
├─8385 danted: request
├─8388 danted: request
├─8395 danted: request
├─8399 danted: request
├─8400 danted: io-chil
├─8506 danted: request
├─8508 danted: negotia
└─8510 danted: request

Oct 01 10:58:14 johnjoseph-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
Oct 01 10:58:14 johnjoseph-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).

==============================================================

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general Linux config or admin issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Thanks kaylum for sharing those links, posted now. And it was solved so I can close this as well

Answer (score 0):

i belive that firewall block some port
maybe u should try this
#ufw disable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).